# How to bind files to input[type="file"] in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div which was dropzone to drop file(s) in the div,

```
<div id="dropZone"></div>
<input type="file" id=fileUpload"/>
```

I want to bind drop files to the html file type "fileUpload" control. I have tried like
but not getting. is it possible?

I have written the script for the div

```
  $('#dropZone').bind('dragenter', ignoreDrag);
  $('#dropZone').bind('dragover', ignoreDrag);



  $('#dropZone').bind('drop', function (e) {
   drop(e);
  });
```

**Edited and Added  script**

```
     //Updated
     function ignoreDrag(e) {
        e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
        e.originalEvent.preventDefault();
    }
   //Updated End
```

and in the drop function

```
  function drop(e) {
        ignoreDrag(e);

        var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
        var droppedFiles = dt.files;

        if (dt.files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < dt.files.length; i++) {
                var fileName = droppedFiles[0].name;
                $("#lblMsg").show();
                $("#spnFile").text(fileName);

                var formData = new FormData();

                formData.append("fileUploaded", droppedFiles);
                alert(dt.files[0]);
                $("#fileUploaded").bind("val", dt.files[0]); 
                // Binding to file(s) to the <input type="file"/> but not binding.
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this possible to bind like above??

Comment: You need to ignore `dragover` and `dragenter` events. You have a call to `ignoreDrag` that might be doing it (I can't see the source for that), but it's doing it from inside the `drop` handler, which is never invoked because `dragover` and `dragenter` are not ignored.

Comment: I have edited, please check it, but i think it is not a problem.

Comment: It is a problem, because you need to ignore `dragover` and `dragenter` events on an element for it to be considered droppable. Try `$('#dropZone').bind('dragover', ignoreDrag).bind('dragenter', ignoreDrag)`

Comment: Yes doing that one, i have not added in  my question pane. still it is not getting.